# Where does TeXWorks put auxiliary and log files?

Tags: texworks

I got a new PC and hence a new TeXWorks installation. TeXWorks or MikTeX now puts all auxiliary and log files in some directory. Does anyone know, where I can find these files? Can I configure TeXWorks in a way such that it put all files in the working directory, like my old instalation did?

Answer (score 3):

Go to menu `Edit -> Preferences`, `Typesetting` tab:

[image]

click on the `Edit...` button to launch the `Tool Configuration`:

[image]

Select an engine: in the `Arguments` window, you should have a line like `--aux-directory=...`. Just click on the `–` button to remove it.

If you want to change the location, remove it, then click on the `+` button to add a new path (the path is relative to the current directory).